# SQL SELECT Difference between two days greater than 1 day

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause, days

I have table T1

```
ID  SCHEDULESTART         SCHEDULEFINISH
1   2018-05-12 14:00:00   2018-05-14 11:00:00
2   2018-05-30 14:00:00   2018-06-01 11:00:00
3   2018-02-28 14:00:00   2018-03-02 11:00:00
4   2018-02-28 14:00:00   2018-03-01 11:00:00
5   2018-05-30 14:00:00   2018-05-31 11:00:00
```

I want to select all rows where difference in days (it's not important difference in hours) is greater than 1 day.
If SCHEDULESTART or SCHEDULEFINISH are on the same day or SCHEDULEFINISH is on next day then these rows should NOT be selected.
So the result should return rows with IDs:  `1 2 3`
because first row have difference in two days, second row (1st June is 2 days after 30th May ) and 3rd row (2nd March is 2 days after 28 February).
Is this possible somehow?
I know the function `DAY` but this will return only day number in that one month!!!
I must beging my query with

```
SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oracle, firebird, mssql? I would guess `datediff` could be used.

Comment: DB2 (IBM database). I tagged it

Comment: @Sk1X1 . . . You can click on the tags to see what they mean.  If you click on "db2" you'll see that it refers to a "specific" database, produced by IBM.  I put "specific" in quotes, because there are a myriad of versions of it, given that it is one of the oldest relational databases out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2, this should work:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where date(schedulestart) < date(schedulefinish) - 1 day;
```